# Can I power a Windows 95-era AT PC with an ATX PSU, like this?

Tags: ibm-pc, power

Is this the correct way to make the adapter? Will the "15A 120V AC ONLY" switch damage anything? The switch is illuminated. (glows when off)

[image: schematic]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126320/discussion-on-question-by-user21987-can-i-power-a-windows-95-era-at-pc-with-an-a).

Comment: Note that new Specification 2.01 has deprecated the -5V rail, so you may have to use a `LM7905`: 1) GND 2) -12V from PSU 3) -5V to AT P9

Comment: The switch won't glow. The switch needs 120V AC to glow. It will still work as a switch though.

Comment: @Stavr00: Damn, beat me to it (more details [here](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/power-trouble/)).

Answer (score 4):

I second @Raffzahn the on switch is just low voltage low power digital switch its most likely just +5V or +3.3V and just few mA or less depending on the gates so using 15A/120V switch for it is overkill.

Its most likely **meant to reusing the original AT case power switch** for this.

In practice usually just a short-cutting wire put directly to connector is used instead (permanently on and use the PSU backside switch to on/off).

However **beware** in case your AT on/off switch contains also **filtering resonator** (part usually enclosed in plastic or ceramic casing with 3 4 or 6 pins) or **dampening coils**  both would be very close to the switch, that should be bypassed as it might damage the PSU when used on its digital side.

Also **check if the switch is not connected to case ground**  if it is disconnect it. You know case ground and digital GND are not the same !!! If you can't disconnect the grounding (some are fixed permanently with bolts) then its not safe to use it and **impose a great hazard** not just to PSU... (both health, fire and PC damage even damage crossing other devices through power cord or even signal cables like network sound ...).

The glowing is most likely just a glowing tube that does not work on low voltages so it should be fine...

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩 heh you beat me by 11 seconds was just about to repair the same :)  ... weird usually the site prevent to enter edit mode if it already is in it for other user... we had to hit the edit button in very small time frame

Comment: You can always edit your own posts, regardless of whether another user is editing.

Comment: @TobySpeight not this time .. editor worked fine however saving the changes was not allowed for me

Comment: My PSU works fine when using the wall light switch.

Comment: @Spektre, that's what I meant - another user editing won't block the post's owner from _starting_ to edit.  And whoever saves first wins, which can be frustrating.

Comment: @user21987 then you in luck as is most likely not grounded nor connected to any filters ... however to be sure you should check it (there must be no connection to chassis and no suspicious parts around the switch)

Comment: @TobySpeight they changed behavior? Or its just SE/RC ... I remeber (unless my brain is playing trick on me) The edit button will throw an popup its disabled during already present edit...

Comment: @Spektre Is it better to connect the wall light switch to PS_ON and GND and turn that switch on and off, or use the PSU's switch? Can repeated switching of the PSU's switch reduce its life?

Comment: Not if you're the _owner_ of the post.  It's been like that as long as I can remember, and makes sense (otherwise a malicious person could lock the owner out of their own post).  Sorry, two discussions at once here - perhaps ask in meta.SE?

Comment: "You know case ground and digital GND are not the same !!!" What? Are you talking about AT power supplies? I've never seen an ATX power supply where case ground != "digital ground" (power ground/black wire).

Comment: @user21987 depends on the power grid quality ... In my case its best to have UPS before PSU and turning it off either with PSU switch or UPS switch as I have a lot of noise in my power cord. However for stable power grid is better to use the digital on/off signal and leave the PSU switch on.

Comment: @OskarSkog switching voltage converters in general ... Even if PEN and GND has 0 Ohm between them in off state that does not mean they are the same and is dangerous to bypass circuitry and short cut them together on the output side ... because then floating effects will occur on blocking ground and possible anywhere else ... I described the usual different grounds a bit in here [Thought I found serial port - broke embedded device instead! Help?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12824/4709)

Comment: What floating effects?  Digital ground is permanently wired to case ground.  Also, what is a "filtering resonator" and "dampening coils"?

Comment: @OskarSkog sorry wrong translation in english the coil is called [choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)) the resonators are passive (high power) band pass filters in US for 60Hz ... to dampen noise going back to power grid ... it should be inside the PSU but I encounter ATs that had it embeded in/near the case power switch to compensate for badly designed PSUs. The blocking ground shortcuts the high frequencies on all ICs however once you bypass it by connecting different ground to PSU output it will no longer do what it is intend for.

Comment: @OskarSkog The current on it will not be equalized meaning it will be no longer near 0V and can gradually increase or decrease even cross to negative values which is a problem fro most digital ICs ... depending on the local pulse load

Comment: That doesn't sound like a fire or electrocution hazard which your answer seems to imply.  Also, the only way it could ever create an extra connection between case ground and power ground is if the switch is connected wrong (PE instead of L or N).  I guess large capacitance and large inductance could cause some issues for PS_ON, but I don't think I'd worry much about it.

Comment: @OskarSkog does not matter how it sounds... Once the control system of a switching PSU is compromised like this anything can happen ...  Seeing melted cables (even FDD and ATA) on blown PC (cause of things like this) where an eye operner...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that wiring is correct for an adapter to connect an ATX supply to an AT motherboard.

You can use any on-off switch you like for turning the ATX supply on, usually ready-made adapters you can buy get wired to a switch that replaces or uses the original AT case mains switch for contolling the ATX supply. By itself, the switch won't damage anything, and is a better way to turn ATX supply on and off than simply hardwiring the PS_ON to GND and using the mains switch on the ATX supply to turn it on and off.

If your switch is an illuminated mains switch, it obviously won't be illuminated, as it most likely requires mains input for lighting up, and now it will be used for switching the ATX logic control input only.

You can also buy one of these adapters as they already exist and they should be identical to your drawing. The original AT mains switch is simply replaced or disconnected from mains wiring and rewired to control the low voltage PS_ON wire of the ATX supply.

Comment: I'd like to update my answer due to the downvote, but I'd need to know the reason for the downvote to do so. People use ATX supplies to power AT motherboards just fine with wiring given in the question or matching ready made cablesets, using the old mains switch to control the ATX PS_ON pin.

Comment: Not sure why the dow-nvote but most likely because of the lack of any checking of the power switch which might pose a big problem ... so `looks like it will work` might be very bad wording as it might not and even might damage a lot more than just PSU

Comment: @Spektre What do you mean lack of any power switch checking? That switch is used exactly the way people have wired ATX to AT adapters for years.

Comment: read my answer ... I encountered some with permanent grounding to case which is a big problem as you are directly connecting source and sink parts of galvanicaly coupled PSU if you not careful... filters are also a big problem that can and will induce negative peaks into PSU control system which usually fries it for good (may be not right away but in time).

Comment: @Spektre But PC metal chassis will already be grounded, inside power supply mains earth is connected to power supply metal and to black 0V wires. AT supplies also may provide the yellow-green wire at the mains power switch where it can be connected to the screw that mounts the mains switch to chassis. Mains switch terminals will not be earthed, they are live&neutral from mains inlet and live&neutral to PSU input.

Comment: Yes and that is exactly the problem as there will be currents between the groundings and floating PSU potentials causing voltage offset on parts of the circuitry where it should not be and I am not talking about few volts here ... it might grow up event to ~200V or more and making havoc even on the low voltage power wires. Have seen too many blown/melted/exloded PSUs and neighboaring circuitry in this way ...

Comment: @Spektre But that is not true, no part of the AT/ATX PSU floats, when properly connected with three-prong earthed mains plug to earthed outlet. The earth wire goes from plug into PSU. PSU metal case is earthed, PC case is earthed via PSU metal case, output black 0V also connects to PSU metal case and is earthed. Nothing floats -  unless you connected the PC into 2-prong socket which has no earth, and this will cause problems and should not be done to begin with. Without earthing, then the metal case will dangerously float via mains Y caps, and so will everything else, and is dangerous.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant ... I encounter some switches will connect case ground to one of the pins and if that is used for on/off of ATX digital signal then the problems starts ... I did not mean disconnect the grounding from case and power cord but grounding from the switch if connected.